# HTML Button Style

Tags: html, css

how could i get a button to look like the "Check It" button on this page http://www.intus.co.za/

Comment: I highly recommend you download and install the firebug plugin for firefox. I'd never to web development without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input class="field" type="submit" style="margin-right: 10px;" value="Check It"/>
```

CSS:

```
.field {
border:1px solid #000000;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
}
```

I got this using Firebug (a Firefox plugin).

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to do this much, get Firebug, and simply inspect the element you like.  It shows:

```
<input class="field" type="submit" onclick="javascript:popup();return false;" style="margin-right: 10px;" value="Check It"/>

.field {
  border:1px solid #000000;
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything you want to try to duplicate on the web ought to be checked out with Firebug:
http://getfirebug.com

You can see the HTML and CSS (and JavaScript for that matter) that you'd need.

Answer (score 1):

I used the element inspector in [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1843) and it shows this for the button.

```
element.style {
margin-right:10px;
}

.field {
border:1px solid #000000;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

style="border: 1px #000 solid"

Answer (score 0):

...or, if you use IE, there's the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).